# R - Suppress try() output to console when trapping an Rselenium expression

Tags: r, try-catch, rselenium, suppressmessage

The following code sends output to the console when the expression fails even though the `try()` argument `silent = TRUE`.

```
dd = try(unlist(remDr$findElement("css", "#ctl00_mainA")), silent = TRUE)
```

`suppressMessages()` does not suppress the output.

```
dd = suppressMessages(try(unlist(remDr$findElement("css", "#ctl00_mainA")), silent = TRUE))
```

try() is used to trap the error `Selenium message: Unable to locate element: ........`. The code logic works perfectly; the script continues to run as intended.

The message is not an Error that appears in red. The message is in black; the same color that results from print() and cat().

Echo is off. The source code does not print to the console.

I want to suppress the message while retaining the ability to send messages to the console with print() and cat().

Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: There is an updated version on github. You can install with `devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")`.

Comment: Well try using `tryCatch()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `remDr$findElements()` instead with the same arguments. If the element you are looking for doesn't exist it just returns a zero length `list` which is easy to test for, and you don't get a lengthy error message printed to the console.